# Can anybody tell me what this piece of R code does?

Tags: r, rstudio

```
set.seed(1234)
dataPartition <- sample(2,nrow(data),replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.7,0.3))      
trainData <- data[dataPartition ==1,]
testData <- [dataPartition ==2,]
```

Comment: Why don't you run it and find out?

Answer (score 2):

It partition your data into two groups.

```
       sample(2,nrow(data),replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.7,0.3))
```

You sample a vector in the length of your matrix which is composed of 1 and 2 with probability of 0.7 and 0.3.

```
       trainData <- data[dataPartition ==1,]
        testData <- data[Partition ==2,] ## Fixed the brackets
```

This is just to divide your data into two in order to be able (i presume) validate a model. 
Here is a more detailed answer to why divide your data into train and test 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set